# Adjust caption for the second figure

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, captions

I am very new to latex from msword. However I am loving it already. Forgive me if my question is too basic.
I need to align the second caption like the first one. The Minimum Working code is

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{flower1}
    % first figure itself
    \caption{The beautiful flower as downloaded }
 \end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    
    \includegraphics[height=0.7\textwidth]{flower2}
    % second figure itself
   \caption{The second one}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have substituted the original images with exactly the images of same dimension and captions with exactly the same number of characters so that the environment can be exactly simulated. I have experimented with all the numerical values in my code but could not achieve the desired result. At present it is beyond my Latex knowledge.
[image: flower1.png]
[image: flower2.png]

Comment: Also if you think the code can be optimized, I will love to learn it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I understand you correctly, you want to top align the two captions. Is that correct? How would you like the two images themselves to be aligned with respect to each other?

Comment: If you run the code with my images, you will see that the second image and it's caption is not properly alighned as the first one. I want the second caption to be aligned as first one. Thanx. Alignment position and image size should not change, only the second caption should move a bit right to be aligned centrally with the second image.

Comment: If I run the code from your question with the exact same image, I get the following output:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtNnR.png I honestly don't see any improper alignment here. Maybe you can add an annotated screenshot of the output you get to your question?

Comment: You got exactly the same output as mine. The second image should move a bit right to be centrally aligned with the second caption.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. A solution to that will heavily depend on the width of the actual caption that you want to use in your real document. Will it be shorter than a single line?

Comment: The current captions contains exactly the same number of characters as the original ones. So anything you suggest here can be directly applied to the original one. Also if you think the code can be further optimized, I will love to learn that as I am a beginner.

Comment: Minipages have optional parameters [t/c/b] for vertical alignment.  [c] (default) aligns the centers, [t] aligns the first baseline, and [b] aligns the bottom baseline.  In this case, the cop baseline is the bottom of the image, so you probably want [t].

Comment: @JohnKormylo: As far as I understood the question is about horizontal alignment rather than vertical alignment.

Comment: Kindly try the code and sample images and share the modified output as I am beginner in latex so can't exactly apply the suggestion directly due to my poor command on the software.

Comment: They should be side by side: separated by \hfill (not \par) and less than \textwidth wide.  Unless this is twocolumn, in which case one should use figure*.

Comment: It is single column

Comment: Using article and example-image it works as expected.  I try to avoid document classes which have to be installed from web sites.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: In a [previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550340/adjust-caption-for-the-second-figure?noredirect=1#comment1390018_550340) I showed the output when using the `svjour2` document class. Basically one gets an image that is left aligned with an also left alinged caption. The image is narrower than the caption which itself is shorter than one full line. If I understood the question correctly, the OP now seems to want the narrow image to be horizontally centered with respect to the left aligned caption text.

Comment: JohnKormylo --This is a part of springer journal paper, So document class cannot be changed .  Yes @leandris that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: May be some additional spaces manually installed between the images can solve the problem but I do not know how to do that

Comment: Any suggestions? ☹️